# ! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@collect@child@code

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I do not know if there was any missing character or syntax but I can not understand why I get the error below every time I try to generate the circle.tex file:

```
Runaway argument?
=\tikz@expand \ifx \pgf@let@token (\let \pgfutil@next =\tikz@movetoabs \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfutil@next.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> circle.tex
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{anyfontsize,setspace,fancybox,accsupp,quotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500cm,paperheight=500cm,left=9cm,top=0cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,mindmap,backgrounds}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
\node (energy1) at (30:10cm){Text};
\node (energy2) at (90:10cm) {Text};
%path_1
\draw [circle connection bar] (energy1) edge["USA" {orange ,sloped,above=.5cm,align=center,text width=8cm}] (energy2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `{node [concept] (FOO2)  {FOO};` -> `{node [concept] (FOO2)  {FOO}};`, i.e. add a closing `}`.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
        \tikzset{every node/.style={font=\fontsize{5mm}{5mm}\selectfont,text width=3cm,minimum size=2cm,align=center}}
     \node [concept, text=white,align=left,scale=0.5] at (120:150cm) {Smooth} 
    child [concept color=blue!50, grow=-90,level distance=220]
        {node [concept] (FOO1)  {Texto}}
    child [concept color=blue!50, grow=-90,level distance=220]
        {node [concept] (FOO2)  {FOO}}; 
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 
            \draw[circle connection bar]
        (FOO1) edge (FOO2);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: grateful @marmot, I'm working with a 2000-line code, and that was one of the three mistakes I got when compiling, I consider it a consequence of fatigue. One of the other errors is of type \ iffalse. I'll check if I can resolve the other errors, otherwise I can return to edit this problem.

Comment: @marmot, I have re-edited the issue with more important details.

Comment: Many editors offer syntax highlighting, which show matching brackets. (I didn't use it here but it often helps.)

Comment: Yes, because you say `\usepackage{quotes}` but should say `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`. (I am not a fan of the `quotes` library because there are things that are really tricky, which I was not proposing to use it in the other answer, but you seem to like it...)

Comment: @marmot, I'm editing a parent node with more than 30 childs nodes, I use Vim, but with that amount of child nodes the brackets of the parent node escape from my field of view. I used quotes inside \ usetikzlibrary and everything worked fine now, grateful.